# Difference in conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Why the below query conditions repeating on Join? Is there any effect on this compare to the second query?

1.

```
select *  
FROM  A147_BOMDETAILS_VIEW T1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN A147_INVENTQTYCOSTS_VIEW T2 
    ON (((T1.INVENTCOLORID_COMPONENT=T2.INVENTCOLORID 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID) 
    AND (T1.PARTITION = T2.PARTITION)) 
    AND (T1.INVENTSITEID=T2.INVENTSITEID 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID) 
    AND (T1.PARTITION = T2.PARTITION))) 
    AND (T1.ITEMID_COMPONENT=T2.ITEMID 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID) 
    AND (T1.PARTITION = T2.PARTITION)))?
```

2.

```
select *  
FROM  A147_BOMDETAILS_VIEW T1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN A147_INVENTQTYCOSTS_VIEW T2 
    ON T1.INVENTCOLORID_COMPONENT=T2.INVENTCOLORID 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID) 
    AND (T1.PARTITION = T2.PARTITION 
    AND T1.INVENTSITEID=T2.INVENTSITEID 
    and T1.ITEMID_COMPONENT=T2.ITEMID
```

Thanks,
Work

Answer (score 1):

Those two queries return the same results (after removing the question mark from the first query and correcting the missing ending parenthesis at the end of the second query), but there is a mess of redundant conditions in the first version.

I would expect to see `or` when you have grouped conditions in parenthesis like that, but there is only `and`. You can ditch the parenthesis and simplify to:

```
select *
from A147_BOMDETAILS_VIEW T1
  left join A147_INVENTQTYCOSTS_VIEW T2
    on T1.INVENTCOLORID_COMPONENT = T2.INVENTCOLORID
   and T1.DATAAREAID = T2.DATAAREAID
   and T1.partition = T2.partition
   and T1.INVENTSITEID = T2.INVENTSITEID
   and T1.ITEMID_COMPONENT = T2.ITEMID
```